# Made a die simulator in python any way to improve it?

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python as an assignment and have made a die simulator and I had to create an if case for each possible number. Is there a way to improve this code so I can shorten the command for the dice command ?

##Code##

```py
    import random
    
    def roll():
        x=random.randint(1,6)
        return x
    
    def dice(x):
        if x==1:
            print('['," "," "," ",']')
            print('['," ","O"," ",']')
            print('['," "," "," ",']')
        elif x==2:
            print('['," "," "," ",']')
            print('[',"O"," ","O",']')
            print('['," "," "," ",']')
        elif x==3:
            print('[',"O"," "," ",']')
            print('['," ","O"," ",']')
            print('['," "," ","O",']')
        elif x==4:
            print('[',"O"," ","O",']')
            print('['," "," "," ",']')
            print('[',"O"," ","O",']')
        elif x==5:
            print('[',"O"," ","O",']')
            print('['," ","O"," ",']')
            print('[',"O"," ","O",']')
        elif x==6:
            print('[',"O"," ","O",']')
            print('[',"O"," ","O",']')
            print('[',"O"," ","O",']')
    
    holder=True 
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        while holder==True:
            user_choice=input("Do you want to throw the die ?")
            user_choice.lower()
            if user_choice[0]=='y':
                dice(roll())
            elif user_choice[0]=='n':
                print("Come again later")
                holder=False
                break
            else:
                print("Please enter y/n")
```

Comment: those print statements can be values in a dict first of all, and you wouldnt need the mock switch, just put \n newline characters in it and name the value "1", "2" etc, then you can reference each one with the actual number like print(myDict[x])

Comment: This might be better-suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: The post was closed for asking multiple questions. As I am new to stackoverflow I did not know that but now I have removed the multiples asked and focused on a single question. Hope it reopens the post.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than have your `dice` function print the die face directly to stdout, you should consider returning the value and letting the caller do the right thing to it. Indeed an abstraction probably isn't wrong here.

```py
class Die:
    dice_faces = {
        1: '''\
[   ]
[ o ]
[   ]''',
        2: '''\
[o  ]
[   ]
[  o]''',
        3: '''\
[o  ]
[ o ]
[  o]''',
        4: '''\
[o o]
[   ]
[o o]''',
        5: '''\
[o o]
[ o ]
[o o]''',
        6: '''\
[o o]
[o o]
[o o]'''}

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dice_faces[self.value]

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    # Could even have a random roller in here too
    @classmethod
    def random(cls):
        value = random.randint(1, 6)
        return cls(value)
```

Then your main code would look like:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # I'm going to skip the user prompting and just print a dice roll
    die = Die.random()  # using that alternate constructor above
    print(die)
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the multiple conditions, others have shown using a dictionary, but I prefer doing things the way you did them. In other languages you can use a switch statement, but that doesn't exist in Python. Here are the other changes I would make.

The dice function would Perhaps be better named something like display_dice. Or draw_dice or output_dice or something like that.

I would make an else condition in the dice function that raises an error if something unexpected was passed in. It helps you avoid situations were you have a difficult time figuring out were the program went wrong when you raise an error as soon as you notice that something isn't right.

You can get rid of the holder variable in your while loop since saying `break` is the same thing as `holder=False`. Your loop would then look like

```
while True:
    user_choice=input("Do you want to throw the die ?").lower()
    if user_choice[0]=='y':
        dice(roll())
    elif user_choice[0]=='n':
        print("Come again later")
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter y/n")
```

Some things that I like about your code is the way that you separated the roll function from the dice function makes a lot of sense. And the way you checked the input by first lowercasing the input and then only grabbing the first character is the way yes/no prompts should be done.